# App works on emulator but not real device

Tags: java, android

I just uploaded my app to google play and then installed it on my android phone which is running android 2.3.5. Anyways everything worked perfect on the emulator but crashes right on start up on the real device. Any ideas? here's the code.

```
public class StopWatch extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    //PROPERTIES USED THROUGHOUT CLASS
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private TextView stopWatchC;
    private Button startButton,stopButton,resetButton;
    private RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    private Handler handle;
    private Handler backHand = new Handler();
    private boolean timerIsRunning;
    private boolean previouslyStarted;
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;
    private long runTime;
    private long UPDATE_EVERY = 200;
    private int backgrounds[] = {
            R.drawable.woman_1,
            R.drawable.woman_2,
            R.drawable.woman_3,
            R.drawable.woman_4,
            R.drawable.woman_5,
            R.drawable.woman_6,
            R.drawable.woman_7,
            R.drawable.woman_8,
            R.drawable.woman_9
            }; 
    //END PROPERTY DECLARATIONS
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stopwatch);
        //Start our service
        startService(new Intent(this,StopwatchService.class));
       //SETUP BUTTON AND TEXTVIEWS
        stopWatchC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        //Handles listening for clicks on our start,stop and reset buttons
        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Calls run method for changing backgrounds
        backHand.postDelayed(backgroundUpdate, 300);    

    }
    /**
     * Handles displaying the counter
     */
    public void SWCounterDisplay()
    {
    String display;
    long now;
    long difference;
    long secs;
    long mins;
    long hours;

    if(timerIsRunning == true)
    {
        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }else{
        now = endTime;
    }
    if(previouslyStarted == true){
    difference = runTime + (now - startTime);   
    }else{
    difference = now-startTime;
    }
    //No negative numbers
    if(difference < 0)
    {
        difference = 0;
    }

    secs = difference/1000;
    mins = secs/60;
    hours = mins/60;
    secs = secs%60;
    mins = mins%60;

    display = String.format("%d", hours) + ":" +
              String.format("%02d",mins) + ":" +
              String.format("%02d", secs);

              stopWatchC.setText(display);

    }
    /**
     * Reset the timer
     */
    public void resetTimer()
    {
        timerIsRunning = false;
        previouslyStarted = false;
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        runTime = 0;
        SWCounterDisplay();
        handle.removeCallbacks(timerUpdate);
        handle = null;
    }
    /**
     * Starts the stop watch 
     */
    public void startTimer()
    {
        timerIsRunning = true;
        stopButton.setEnabled(timerIsRunning);
        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        if(!previouslyStarted){
        previouslyStarted = true;   
        runTime = 0;
        }
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Create new handler
        handle = new Handler();
        handle.postDelayed(timerUpdate, UPDATE_EVERY);  

    }
    /**
     * Stops the timer
     */
    public void stopTimer()
    {
        timerIsRunning = false;
        stopButton.setEnabled(timerIsRunning);
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        runTime += endTime-startTime;
        handle.removeCallbacks(timerUpdate);
        handle = null;
    }
    /**
     * Handles any onClick events
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v == startButton)
        {
            startTimer();
        }else if(v == stopButton)
        {
            stopTimer();
        }else if(v == resetButton)
        {
            resetTimer();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Changes the background every 20 Seconds
     */
    private Runnable backgroundUpdate = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
          mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(backgrounds[rand.nextInt(backgrounds.length)]);
          backHand.postDelayed(this, 60000);
        }

    };
    /**
     * Handles updating the timer
     */
    private Runnable timerUpdate = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SWCounterDisplay(); 
            if(handle != null){
            handle.postDelayed(this, UPDATE_EVERY); 
            }

        }

    };
    /**
     * Call run method if timer is still running 
     */
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        if(timerIsRunning == true)
        {
            handle = new Handler();
            handle.postDelayed(timerUpdate, UPDATE_EVERY);  
        }
    }
    /**
     * Stop the timer if timer is still running
     */
    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        if(timerIsRunning == true)
        {
            handle.removeCallbacks(timerUpdate);
            handle = null;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Resume when the onResume method is called
     */
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if(timerIsRunning == true){ 
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        SWCounterDisplay();
    }

package com.webdeveloper93.stopwatch;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class StopwatchService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId)
    {
        Log.d("StopwatchService:","SERVICE STARTED");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.d("StopwatchService:","SERVICE DESTROYED");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT

```
I/ActivityManager(  132): No longer want com.google.android.gsf.login (pid 1140): hidden #16
D/WifiService(  132): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluggedType: 0
I/ActivityManager(  132): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.webdeveloper93.stopwatch/.StopWatch } from pid 231
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.StrictMode$VmPolicy$Builder.detectLeakedClosableObjects
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at com.webdeveloper93.stopwatch.StopWatch.onCreate(StopWatch.java:59)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  132):   Force finishing activity com.webdeveloper93.stopwatch/.StopWatch
W/ActivityManager(  132): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{408ff850 com.webdeveloper93.stopwatch/.StopWatch}
W/InputMethodManagerService(  132): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@405ca178
I/ActivityManager(  132): Process com.webdeveloper93.stopwatch (pid 1186) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  132): Service crashed 2 times, stopping: ServiceRecord{4078c080 com.webdeveloper93.stopwatch/.StopwatchService}
W/ActivityManager(  132): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{408ff850 com.webdeveloper93.stopwatch/.StopWatch}
I/ActivityManager(  132): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.jtb.alogcat/.LogActivity } from pid 231
```

Comment: Please could you post the logcat with your question?

Comment: *"but crashes right on start up on the real device"* Please show the crash error message (Logcat)

Comment: Was the emulator configured for Android 2.3.5?  What is your Min SDK in the manifest file?

Comment: Can't really help you without a logcat message

Comment: I don't have no usb to connect my device for debugging is the log cat from the emulator ok? even tho it works fine on there

Comment: @user3325917 If it's working fine, no that's useless. We need the log from the real device. If you don't have an usb cable to connect your device, you can install [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=fr) on your device and share the log here after.

Comment: Ok ill do thank i didn't even know about aLogcat :)

Comment: Ok I added the log cat to my post thanks again

Comment: Oh i know the issue i believe. Before i posted the code i did have strict mode on and removed it now. Which would relate to this line im sure NoSuchMethodError: android.os.StrictMode$VmPolicy$Builder.detectLeakedClosableObjects anyways im sure the newest uploaded apk just hasn't took effect because i did remove strict mode so hopefully that will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use a method which is not implemented in android <=2.3.5. If you remove `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`, you will see which one it is.

I think it works in your emulator because you use a higher sdk-version there.

Comment: Thanks ya i removed tht method now i just have to wait for my newly upload apk to take effect thanks again tho :)